# Java: how it is possible to call method directly using class name

Tags: java

As i know whenever  we want to call any method then we create object and invoke its method using `obj.methodname`.

But below program calls the method of `E` class without creating object. How this is possible? Please anyone help me to understand this concept.

**I mean** 'From below code, how this is possible to write `E.test2();`? , i think it should be `E obj=new E(); obj.test2();`

```
    class E
{
    int i;
    static int j;

    void test1()
    {
        System.out.println("From test1");
    }
    static void test2()
    {
        System.out.println("From test2");
    }
}

class F extends E
{
    int m;
    static int n; 
    void test3()
    {
        System.out.println("From test3");
    }
    static void test4()
    {
        System.out.println("From test4");
    }
}

public class G {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        E.test2();
        F.test2();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `static` method can be called by the class name becuase they belong to `Class` not to any `instance` of the `Class` so they can be called using the `Class name` .I will reccomend you to go to below link and read it completely.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `E.test2` is declared as `static` which means that you can use this method without create an instance of that class. There are so many classes in Java that uses it.

See the docs:

[Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: oh thanks,  i did not seen that `static` in front of my method. so i asked d this question. Actually i know static member can be called using class-name. I can accept ur answer only after 5 mins

Answer (score 2):

test2 method is static in class E , and static method are class specific not object specific ,and they are accessed using  "classname.methodname" syntax.
where methodname is static method of "classname"

Answer (score 1):

static methods can be called using class name and do not require an object of that class.

Please read this: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/21function/

Comment: But how can you say `class E`is static?`

Comment: A class does not need to be static. The mehod inside E needs to be.

Comment: `E` isn't static (this isn't even possible for top-level classes). It's the method that's static. `E` is just there to designate what class holds the `static` method.