# Instance methods can access instance methods directly. What does this mean?

Tags: java

After going through Java documentation I understand that a field declared with 'static' keyword is class variable (or static field) and similarly when using 'static' during method declaration, is a static method (or class method). Class variable and Class methods are reference by class name itself.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257721/java-how-it-is-possible-to-call-method-directly-using-class-name) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006799/is-it-possible-to-access-instance-methods-and-variable-via-class-methods) topics however could not understand following sentences from Java documentation.

What does it mean when it says..... 
Not all combinations of instance and class variables and methods are allowed:

1. Instance methods can access instance variables and instance methods
   directly.
2. Instance methods can access class variables and class methods
   directly.
3. Class methods can access class variables and class methods directly.

The Java doc clearly explains about Class variables and Class methods but above 3 points are confusing to me.

Comment: If you remove the word `static`, what kind of variable is it? It **is** an instance variable (or instance method). So if you don't have `static`, then you can call other methods (and access other variables) that are **not** `static`. You can also access the `static` variables and methods. However, if you are in a `static` block or method, then you can only access other `static`s. That is all those three sentences say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Example Execution](http://jdoodle.com/a/o77)

> 1.Instance methods can access instance variables and instance methods directly.

**Some Info:**

- Instance method are methods which require an object of its class to be 
  created before it can be called.To invoke a instance method, we have to 
  create an Object of the class in within which it defined.
- Instance variables are declared in a class, but outside a method, constructor 
  or any block.

  ```
  class Example1 {
      int a = 100; // instance variable

      public void printData() { // this an instance method called using an object of class Example1
          getData(); // accessing another instance method directly without any object
      }

      public void getData() {

          System.out.println(a); // accessing instance variable 'a' directly without any object
      }

  }

  public class InstanceDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Example1 obj1 = new Example1();
      obj1.printData(); // will print 100
  }
  }
  ```

> 2.Instance methods can access class variables and class methods directly.

- Class variables also known as static variables are declared with the static 
  keyword in a class, but outside a method, constructor or a block.

  ```
      class Example2 {
      static int a = 20; // 'static' / class variable

      public void printData() { // instance method
          setData(); // accessing class method directly
          System.out.println(a); // accessing class variable directly
      }

      public static void setData() { // class method 'static'

          a = 200; // setting value of class variable 'a'
      }

      }


  public class InstanceDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      Example2 obj2 = new Example2();
      obj2.printData(); // will print 200
  }   
  }
  ```

> 3.Class methods can access class variables and class methods directly.

- Static methods are the methods in Java that can be called without creating an 
  object of class. They are referenced by the class name itself or reference to 
  the Object of that class.
- **Memory Allocation:** They are stored in Permanent Generation space of heap as 
  they are associated to the class in which they reside not to the objects of 
  that class. But their local variables and the passed argument(s) to them are 
  stored in the stack. Since they belong to the class so they can be called to 
  without creating the object of the class.

  ```
  class Example3 {
      static int a = 300;

      public static void printData() {
          getData(); // accessing class method
      }

      public static void getData() {

          System.out.println(a); // accessing class variable 'a'
      }

  }

  public class InstanceDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      //calling class method : class method are called using class name. 
      Example3.printData(); // will print 300
  }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to practice programming, so you can experience how the language works. Understanding the quirks of static access is one of the hardest things to grasp initially. Static members are generally geared towards providing class utility.

An instance method gets a pointer to the instance it's operating on, on the stack, therefore it can access the members of the instance. A static method isn't associated with any particular instance. There's no 'this' reference, thus it can't access instance members.

Answer (score 0):

> Instance methods can access instance variables and instance methods
>   directly.

This means a method that doesn't have a `static` modifier i.e. an *instance method* can access any non-static variable as well as call any non-static method.

> Instance methods can access class variables and class methods
>   directly.

This means a method that doesn't have a `static` modifier i.e. an *instance method* can access a `static` variable or call a method with the `static` modifier.

> Class methods can access class variables and class methods directly.

This means a `static` method can access any `static` variable as well as call any other method that has a `static` modifier.

---

To put it simply, an instance method i.e. a method without the `static` modifier can access both a `static` variable as well as a non-static variable and it can also directly call a static method and a non-static method.

On the other hand, a `static` method can only access `static` variables and call `static` methods. it cannot, however, access an instance variable or instance methods directly without an object.